# Getting the value from a custom input widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I made a custom input widget by wrapping Textfield in some widgets and so on. Now I can't reach the onChanged property directly from the custom widget. I tried making a property in my custom widget but couldn't implement it properly. I googled passing variables between widgets and it seems a hard thing to do. Any simple solution?

```
class Input extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextInputType type;
  final int maxLength;
  final bool password;
  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
  final double padding;
  final Function onChanged;
  final ColorSwatch color;

  Input(
      {this.type = TextInputType.text,
      @required this.text,
      this.maxLength,
      this.icon,
      this.padding = 0.0,
      this.password = false,
      @required this.onChanged,
      this.label,
      this.color});

  final String value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Text(
              text + ":",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: color),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            width: 300.0,
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: password,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: label,
                icon: Icon(icon),
              ),
              maxLength: maxLength,
              keyboardType: type,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. Can you show a sample of what you have?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `onChanged` and other events in your custom widget, even if you are just providing these to the underlying TextField. In other words, *you* need to pass the onChanged function down through your custom widget.

For example:

```
MyAwesomeTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Callback for being notified of changes to the text field
  /// This should have a proper type, I'm just using Function for simplicity
  final Function onChanged; 

  // Make the onChanged property settable through the constructor
  MyAwesomeTextField({this.onChanged});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Construct your widget tree, and pass your onChanged function through
    return TextField(onChanged: this.onChanged);
  }
}
```

Then when you're using it, your custom widget will have an onChanged event:

```
...
MyCustomWidget(onChanged: (value) => print(value) )
...
```

Comment: `Function` is back. You likely want things like `ValueChanged<String>` or `VoidCallback`.

Comment: this really worked thank you, I tried something similar earlier like `final void Function() onChanged;` but it didn't work.